# change the value in input field on radio click

Tags: jquery, html

i am working on a project where user has to select an option among two. options are radio buttons. currently i am getting the result on keyup event. when user select one option and then enter the the value in input field he got the result in another result input field. its working fine but the problem arise when user want to change the option and select the other option now he has to enter the value again in input field which is not correct what i want to do is when he select the other option the result should automatically change in result input field as he already enter a value once in input filed.

here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wr4Xv/28/) for whole process

here is html:

```
       <td>
       <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-day" value="25" class="rdbtn-style-social"  />Daily&nbsp;
       <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-week" value="25" class="rdbtn-style-social"  />Weekly
       </td>
```

here is result input

```
          result<input type="text"  name="final_res" id="final_res" class=""  style="width:100px;margin: 2px;"/>
```

here is my jquery

```
     var val = 0;

     jQuery("#rdbtn-im-day").click( function(){
    if( jQuery(this).is(":checked") ){ // check if the radio is checked
         val = jQuery(this).val(); // retrieve the value
    }
    });

    jQuery("#rdbtn-im-week").click( function(){
    if( jQuery(this).is(":checked") ){ // check if the radio is checked
         val = jQuery(this).val() * 7; // retrieve the value
    }
   });  

   jQuery("#txt_im").keyup(function(){ 
   var txt_value =  jQuery(this).val();
    var res = txt_value * val;

    var final = parseInt(res);
    var MBresult = final/1024;

    jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));
```

i am using jquery-1.3.2.min.js which was not avaialble in the right dropdown list.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your functionality:

- Remove the click events on radio instead use a change event.
- Change you radio button markup to set the actual value rather than doing a calculation later on
- No need to use the variable `val` to maintain the value of radio button checked.

#### Script

```
jQuery("#txt_im").keyup(setValue); // on keyup of textbox call the function to calculate
jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]').change(setValue); // on keyup of textbox call the function to calculate

function setValue() {
    var txt_value = jQuery("#txt_im").val(); //Get the textbox val
    var rad_val = jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]:checked').val(); //Get the checked radio val

    if (!txt_value.length || !rad_val.length) return; // Don't do if either of them is not available
    var res = txt_value * rad_val;
    var final = parseInt(res, 10);
    var MBresult = final / 1024;
    jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));
}
```

#### Radio Markup Section

```
<input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-day" value="25" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Daily&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-week" value="175" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Weekly</td>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/)**

Comment: var final = parseInt(res, 10); what do you mean by 10 here as we can use it like var final = parseInt(res);. can you explain a little bit

Comment: but when i remove the entered value in the input field the result should also get empty http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/