# on remove value from input should also remove the resulted value

Tags: jquery

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258116/change-the-value-in-input-field-on-radio-click/17258183?noredirect=1#comment25026958_17258183) few days before. Also see [accompanied fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/). Now i have one more question regarding this, that when a user remove the entered value in input field then the result should also be set to zero. I don't have any idea how to do it.

Here is the code that do the whole functionality:

```
jQuery("#txt_im").keyup(setValue);
jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]').change(setValue);

function setValue() {
    var txt_value = jQuery("#txt_im").val();
    var rad_val = jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]:checked').val();

    if (!txt_value.length || !rad_val.length) return;
    var res = txt_value * rad_val;
    var final = parseInt(res, 10);
    var MBresult = final / 1024;
    jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2)); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look modified [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/1/):

```
jQuery("#txt_im").keyup(setValue);
jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]').change(setValue);

function setValue() {
    var txt_value = jQuery("#txt_im").val();
    var rad_val = jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]:checked').val();
    if(!txt_value.length) {
        jQuery('#final_res').val('');
        return;        
    }

    if (!rad_val.length) return;
    var res = txt_value * rad_val;
    var final = parseInt(res, 10);
    var MBresult = final / 1024;        

    jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));   
 }
```

Comment: yes it works but there is a problem in it it totally finish the value it should be but i put a part of my cod kindly check this fiddle this is the whole seen  http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/7/ and this question which will help you in understanding the issue and i know you can help me as you did once  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315254/entry-in-input-one-by-one-should-show-added-result-in-result-field