# entry in input one by one should show added result in result field

Tags: javascript, jquery

when user select any option in radio buttons in group one and then enter any number in respective input field and then select the next any radio option and enter any value in input field then this time it should add the new result with old one and display it in result input field and now if he empty any input field then that should also minus from the total result and display it in result field.

i have so many groups like that but here i just put two of them to get the result.

here id the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/7/)

here is the jquery code. i can work in jquery but not very good i used separate code for every group and i know there must be a way to get this whole functionality through generic code but again i am not good at jquery

```
 jQuery("#txt_im").keyup(setValue);
 jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]').change(setValue);

function setValue() {
var txt_value = jQuery("#txt_im").val();
var rad_val = jQuery('[name="rdbtn-im"]:checked').val();
if(!txt_value.length) {
    jQuery('#final_res').val('');
    return;        
}

if (!rad_val.length) return;
var res = txt_value * rad_val;
var final = parseInt(res, 10);
var MBresult = final / 1024;


jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));

}

var final2 = 0;

jQuery("#txt_fb").keyup(setValue2); 
jQuery('[name="rdbtn-fb"]').change(setValue2);

function setValue2() {


var txt_value = jQuery("#txt_fb").val();

var rad_val = jQuery('[name="rdbtn-fb"]:checked').val();
 if(!txt_value.length) {
    jQuery('#final_res').val('');
     return;   
 }

if (!rad_val.length) return;
var res2 = txt_value * rad_val;
final2 = parseInt(res2, 10) + final;
var MBresult = final2 / 1024;
jQuery('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));


}
```

infact user is free to select any number of groups or also free to remove any number of group after selection.

i know there is error in fiddle when user select 2nd group after the select of first it removes the result which is wron and i tried to solve it but failed but i define the whole seen what i need to do. i will be very thankfull to you for this kind favour.

Comment: my question is viewed 33 times but no one reply???? is there any problem in question??

Comment: Use one function as the binding for all the buttons and inputs. It should combine the values from all of them and put that in the result.

Comment: Respected Barmer can you send me any example link for similar functionality so that i could move forward??

Comment: or can you edit my fiddle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-day" value="25" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Daily&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" id="rdbtn-im-week" value="175" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Weekly
            <input type="text" name="txb3" id="txt_im" class="txt-email" style="width:100px;margin: 2px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sec-td-rdbtns-social">
            <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-fb" id="rdbtn-fb-day" value="3500" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Daily&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-fb" id="rdbtn-fb-week" value="500" class="rdbtn-style-social" />Weekly
            <input type="text" name="txb1" id="txt_fb" class="txt-email" style="width:100px;margin: 2px;" />&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>result
<input type="text" name="final_res" id="final_res" class="" style="width:100px;margin: 2px;" />
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(".txt-email").keyup(setValue);
jQuery('.rdbtn-style-social').change(setValue);

function setValue() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".rdbtn-style-social:checked").each(function () {
        var myInput = $(this).siblings(".txt-email").val();
        if (myInput.length) {
            total += myInput * $(this).val();
        }
    });
    if (total) {
        jQuery('#final_res').val((total / 1024).toFixed(2));
    } else {
        jQuery('#final_res').val('');
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/jC6Xv/14/)

Comment: Thkanks Barmer for reply back but the problem i am looking for solution is still there and also one additional error. when user select 1st daily radio button and then enter any number in input field a final rsult appears in rsult field but now he want to select the any button from 2nd group, it should also be the same he select any button and then enter any number in respective field and rsult appears in rsult field so as he already selecet ist group as well now the combin rsult should appear and also if he remove number from any input field then its result shud also remov from final result

Comment: I've changed the HTML. There were two problems: 1. You didn't have a `<table>` tag, so `<tr>` and `<td>` were ignored. 2. In one row you had the the radio and input in separate `<td>` tags, in the other row you had them in one `<td>`. I put them together in both rows so I could use `.siblings()` to find the input related to the radio button. If you want to separate them, you can use other DOM navigation functions, e.g. `.parent().next().children(".txt-email")`.

Comment: Respected Barmer tou made it finally thanks alot this is what i exactelly need now i can apply it to any number of groups let me try it and if i face any issue i will contact oyu back but for now my hart really want to kiss your forehead. thanks again

Comment: Respected Barmer i made slight change in html and due to which .sibling is not working now check out this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/jC6Xv/15/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome, then console is your best friend ( https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console )
For firefox you have firebug, opera has dragonfly (or something like that ?). Even IE has console now. There you can see all errors popping up.

Ok, so first of all let's clean up this a little bit by wrapping it all in closure (we can now safely use the $ instead of jQuery even if there is namespace conflict outside). Also, we will use single function for both cases, because they are so similar.

```
!function ($) {
    $(".txt-email").keyup(setValue);
    $('.rdbtn-style-social').change(function(e) { setValue(e, true) });

    function setValue(e, radio) {
        if('undefined' === typeof radio) radio = false;
        var attr = radio ? 'name' : 'id';
        var tmp = e.target[attr].split('-');
        var media = tmp[tmp.length - 1];

        var txt_value = $("#txt-"+media).val();
        var rad_val = $('.rdbtn-style-social[name="rdbtn-'+media+'"]:checked').val();
        if (!txt_value.length || !rad_val.length) {
            $('#final_res').val('');
            return false;
        }
        var res = (txt_value | 0) * rad_val;
        var final = parseInt(res, 10);
        var MBresult = final / 1024;
        $('#final_res').val(MBresult.toFixed(2));

    }
}(jQuery);
```

(variable | 0 is same as parseInt(variable, 10)).
So, long story short: when radio or text gets changed, the function is fired (if it's radio, additional argument is passed). We retrieve whether we want to work on im or fb, then do whatever you want. I changed id of inputs to replace _ with -'s (for split consistency)

Final jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiur/f6cxA/1/

Comment: thank you so much Misiur for your reply back but still there are two issues one minor and one major. the minor one is that when user click 2nd group radio as he already select ist group radio then the answer get disappear which is not what i want. major issue which realy put me in the hell is that let user select both the groups and he has now full an final result but now he want to remove any among them e.g he empty the ist one input field now the respective result should be removed from the final result and vise versa. thanks again SIr